# $or condition possibly failing on mongodb 1.2.2 with Mongoose and MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, meanjs

I am using mongodb for my MEAN.JS application.
I have mongodb version 2.6.* installed on my local development machine. While on the remote server I have mongodb version 1.2.2 installed. I am using Mongoose as my ORM.

All other code seems to be working fine on both versions of mongo except the following :

```
RoomAvailability.find({
   'resort_id': checklist.resort_id,
            $or: [{
                'start_date': {
                    $lte: checklist.end_date
                }
            }, {
                'end_date': {
                    $gte: checklist.start_date
                }
            }]
        }, function (err, booked_rooms) {});
```

This find query seems the extract the correct data on my local machine. While on the remote server it returns an empty array for the same set of data.

Is there any syntactical issue? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$or` operator was added in version 1.6 (see [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/query/or/)), so if your remote server is running 1.2.2, it doesn't support `$or`.  You'll need to upgrade that server to use `$or` with it.

1.2.2 is a *really* old version of MongoDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upgrading the mongodb server as you said helped resolve the issue.